# Paging drag and drop Tablesorter plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, paging, tablesorter

I am limited to using tablesorter functionality becuase of hidden child rows under parent rows etc. So I use the "tablesorter mod" functionality http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm

When I try to add dragtable.js and try to drag and drop, only the current page gets rearranged properly. On other pages only the header is shifted leading to mismatch in the data and the header. Is there a work around to have paging, drag and drop and tablesorter functionality all at once. I just want drag and drop to shift the columns for all pages including the displayed page.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.mod.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.collapsible.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="ColReorder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="dragtable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function (){
                $(".tablesorter")
                    /*
                     * td.collapsible = collapse to the first table row and show +/-
                     * td.collapsible_alt = anchor to order number
                     */
                    .collapsible("td.collapsible", {
                        collapse: true
                    })
                    .tablesorter({
                    // set default sort column
                    sortList: [[4,0]],
                    // don't sort by first column
                    headers: {0: {sorter: false}}
                    // set the widgets being used - zebra stripping
                    , widgets: ['zebra']
                    , onRenderHeader: function (){
                        this.wrapInner("<span></span>");
                    }
                    , debug: false
                })
                .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false})
                    ;

                    // Expand/Collapse all
                        $('a#ShowButton').click(function(){
                            var linkLabel = this.innerHTML;
                            switch(linkLabel) 
                            {
                            case "Show History":
                                $("td.collapsible a").removeClass("expanded").click();
                                this.innerHTML= "Hide History"
                                break;
                            case "Hide History":
                                $("td.collapsible a").addClass("expanded").click();
                                this.innerHTML= "Show History"
                                break;
                            }
                        return false;
                        }); 

                        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                        "sDom": 'Rlfrtip'
                        } );


            }

        );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the js code for the page? It would help a lot :)

Comment: @Iro-Posted it below this question

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice? Besides that, jQuery 1.2 is **ancient**.

Comment: @ThiefMaster- Agreed changed it to jquery-1.7.2-min.js still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using the event that is fired on page change/filtering:

```
$("#example").on("draw", function() {
    someFunction();
});
```

In there you could run the drag and drop functions.
Another option is to save the column layout after each drag/drop and then when the table fires draw, re-create that layout. I'm not sure how the plugin you are using works exactly, but i think you could use the draw event and get it to work.